# clip-path does not work with chrome

Tags: css, svg, clip-path

I have problem with `clip-path` in Chrome. Firefox has no problem and shows this html page correctly, but chrome doesn't show anything.

```css
img {
  -webkit-clip-path: url(#clipping); 
          clip-path: url(#clipping); 
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clipping">
      <circle cx="284" cy="213" r="213" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
</svg>

<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnWjF.png" width="728" height="482" >
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webkit does not support applying an SVG clipPath to an html image. If you make the image an SVG image i.e. change the tag to `<image>` and put it inside the `<svg>` element then it will work.

Firefox **does** support applying an SVG clipPath to an HTML image which is why it works there.

Here's an example courtesy of Pancho.

```
<svg width="245" height="180" viewBox="0 0 245 180" >
    <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="something.jpg" width="245" height="180" class="MyClipping" ></image>
</svg>
```

Comment: Could you please show how the correct mark-up would look like in your question?

Comment: @Griffin I got it to work by changing the `<img>` to this : `<svg width="245" height="180" viewBox="0 0 245 180" >
 <image xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xlink:href="something.jpg" width="245" height="180"
     class="MyClipping" ></image>
</svg>` and for the style, instead of using the img tag for styling, I changed it to a class called "MyClipping".

Answer (score 0):

Until now (Jan/2021) Crome seem to not support "*-box" options, i.e. border-box, but supports functions like polygon, etc.