# Clip-Path Inset in CSS not working in chrome

Tags: html, css, clip-path

I'm trying to use the CSS property [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path), but I get an `Invalid property value` error in Chrome.

[image: screenshot]

Here's a small demo:

```css
.clip-me {  
  clip-path: inset(0px 50px 50px 0px); /* top, right, bottom, left */
}
```

```html
<img class="clip-me" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnWjF.png" width="100">
```

[image: Clip Path Example]

*Note*: This is different from this question on [clip-path does not work with chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19227849/1366033), because it's specifically asking about how to apply clip path using SVG (not CSS)

According to Can I Use, it [should work in chrome](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Turns out I just needed the *`-webkit-`* prefix (although I don't see it in this list of [vendor prefixes](http://peter.sh/experiments/vendor-prefixed-css-property-overview/))

```css
.clip-me {           /* top, right, bottom, left */
  -webkit-clip-path: inset(0px 50px 50px 0px); 
          clip-path: inset(0px 50px 50px 0px); 
}
```

```html
<img class="clip-me" src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MnWjF.png" width="100">
```

Update as of **Chrome 55**, clip-path without the vendor prefix is now supported, but many other browsers still require using `-webkit-clip-path` so it's safer to include it for now.

Here's a snapshot of [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-clip-path) (as of 2017), with the additional details in the top right corner of partial support browsers often indicating the need for the *`-webkit-`* prefix

[image: Can I Use Snaptshot]

**Further Reading**:

- [Clipping in CSS and SVG — The clip-path Property and `<clipPath>` Element](http://sarasoueidan.com/blog/css-svg-clipping/)
- [Using clip-path](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/clip/)

Comment: Even [further reading](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19904268/1654265): Lea Verou's PrefixFree

Comment: since when is it clockwise top-right-bottom-left and not x1, y1, x2, y2 ?